# Metrics on $\mathbb Q$.

Tags: real-analysis

Is there a metric on $\mathbb Q$ such that the sequence $(\frac 1 n)$ converges to $1$?

I have no Ansatz to tackle the problem.

Comment: Take the normal distance but switch 0 and 1, ie, $d(x,y) = |x-y|$ if neither are equal to 0 or 1, $d(x,1) = |x|$ and $d(x,0) = |x-1|$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is. The metric is

$$d(x,y)=|f(x)-f(y)|$$

where $$f(x)=\begin{cases} 0 & x=1\\ 1 & x=0 \\ x & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$